# Exception Not Rendering View in Laravel

Tags: laravel

### Summary of Issue

I am unable to get Laravel to render the 500 default error page (views/error/500.php) using Response::error('500').

### Code to Reproduce (simplified for this example)

Create a dummy controller and add the following public method:

```
public function action_index()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception;    
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        Response::error('500');
    }
}
```

When you run this route, notice that you will receive a blank white page and the header status is 200, not 500.

### Expected Outcome

I expect the default 500 error page in views/error/500.php to be rendered and execution of the rest of the script (assuming a longer script) to be stopped.

### Actual Outcome

A blank white page with the header status 200 is sent to the browser.

### My Environment

- Laravel 3.2.12
- PHP 5.3.13 on a shared host
- Windows 7
- Chrome 23 (same results on various other browsers)

### More Information

Is there anything else I can provide to make this issue a little easier to understand or troubleshoot. A similar (identical?) issue came up on the Laravel forums (http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=2191), and it was stated as fixed a while back.

In application/routes.php I have the following code for the 500 error handler:

```
Event::listen('500', function()
{
    return Response::error('500');
});
```

You can see the Response object's source code on GitHub at https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/response.php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your missing the "return". You must always "return".

```
public function action_index()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception;    
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        return Response::error('500');
    }
}
```

Comment: No problems - I only knew because I had the same problem for hours - but at least you'll never do it again :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also return the event, this would give you the same thing right now but allow you to alter behavior in a single place down the line by changing the Event registered.

```
public function action_index()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception;    
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        return Event::first('500');
    }
}
```